# How to configure tomcat for using multiple applications, one of being a fallback?

Tags: tomcat, tomcat6

How can I configure tomcat to take all requests from some applications and use another one as fallback for root.

Example: app1.war, app2.war, app3.war

I want to use app1 for all requests to `/app1/`, for app2 to use `/app2/` and all others requests to be sent to app3.

Update: let's say that adding an Apache before Tomcat is not an option.

Answer (score 1):

Keep the names as they are and only rename app3 to ROOT.war and there you go

app1.war, 
app2.war, 
app3.war (Rename to ROOT.war)

Answer (score 0):

Put Apache HTTP server in front of your Tomcat and use simple [mod_rewrite](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/mod_rewrite.html) rule.

You might also try to experiment with renaming `app3.war` to `ROOT.war` (it will be available in root `/` context)

Comment: If I remember well putting the ROOT.way will absorb all request to this application. Also, I want to put some static files in one of the subdirectiories, like `/static/`.